# Computer's power consumption got really high after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, battery, power-management

I have an HP Envy dv7 laptop (750GB HDD, 8GB RAM, 1600x900 Display). I used to work on Windows 8.1 and the battery used to serve me for 3-4 hours even when using programs that need a lot of processing (Matlab, Android Studio...). Then I upgraded to Windows 10 and power consumption got significantly high. The battery barley serves me for 1.5 hours even when not doing any process, the Disk is most of the times working above 90%, and the laptop gets really hot. Then I reinstalled Windows 8.1 and the power consumption went back to what it used to be. So what is it really that is taking so much power consumption? Would it be something in the upgrade itself?

Comment: analyze the battery usage in Win10: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-157-Energy-Estimation-Engine-E3

Comment: @magicandre1981 If you notice I said that I reinstalled windows 8.1 so analyzing the battery usage for win10 is not possible. I need to know if I re-upgraded to win10, would I have the same problem?

Comment: we can't anser if you get the same issue again. Update to Win10 and follow the steps/tools from the video and look which apps cause the battery drain.